# How can I confirm that this pedigree is of a pseudodominant trait?

Tags: genetics, homework, pedigree

[image]

This is an example of an autosomal recessive trait masquerading as autosomal dominant.  I carried out genetic analysis for each generation as if the trait was either recessive or dominant, and both modes of inheritance seem to fit the pattern observed. Does the pedigree have any defining features that might indicate that it is indeed autosomal recessive? Or would we simply have to carry out further analysis with other pedigrees?

Thanks to anyone that can help

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.